# Javascript Associative Array Key Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, undefined, associative

I have been having a recurring issue with Javacript associative arrays. Basically, I have a piece of code that looks like:

```
var l = assoc['2191'];
console.log(l); // >> outputs 'undefined'
console.log(assoc); // >> correctly outputs the associative array
```

When I print my associative array, it is printed correctly and I can see that '2191' is in fact a key in the array. Even when I go through the javascript console in Chrome, I can type "assoc['2191']" and it correctly returns the associated object. However, whenever I do this in my actual script, it always evaluates to "undefined".

Does anyone know why this has happening? I have checked the type of the key, and "string" is the right choice.

Comment: where and how are you setting your key '2191' for your `assoc` object?

Comment: var assoc= new Array(); assoc[2191] = "test data"; var l = assoc[2191]; console.log(l);  this works as long as your are setting key value correctly

Comment: @HaBo I think that the OP, using the word "associative array", meant *Object*

Comment: check the key is a number and not a string ... assoc[2191] != assoc["2191"]

Comment: @friedi I have an initialization function that runs through a AJAX response and initializes the object. At the end of that loop, it calls a second function that tries to access values and gets 'undefined' for each key.

Comment: @rupps thanks, but I already checked that!

Comment: could you provide the initialization code in a jsfiddle?